# Why this code for start a new activity isn't working?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onclicklistener

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.hello.MESSAGE";

    private EditText text1;

    private EditText text2;

    private Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMessage(v);

            }
        });
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
        String message = text1.getText().toString() + " " + text2.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    }

}
```

My MessageActivity:

```
public class MessageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView.setText("Hello" + message);
    }
}
```

The button is declared in the layout file this way:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:text="@string/main_button_1"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

Anyone can see what's wrong here? The app runs without problem in the emulator, but when I click in the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to call `startActivity(intent)` on `sendMessage(View view)` method.

Ps: To listen the click of the button you need only this:

```
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage(v);

        }
    });
```

or this (in xml), not both.

```
 android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing :

```
 startActivity(intent); in sendMessage()
```